# Não estou conseguindo copiar os caracteres de uma string para outra

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que até que o usuário digitar +, a string digitada vai ser copiada para outra, por exemplo stack+, o a string copiada seria só stack, tentei fazer o código abaixo só que não deu certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nome[100], num1[100];
  int cont,i;
  scanf("%s", nome);
  cont = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < nome[i] != '+'; i++)
  {
     num1[cont] = nome[i];
  }
    num1[cont] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", cont);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C não aceita "Agregar" condições assim o seu for deveria ser "for(i = 0; i < nome[i] **&& nome[i]** != '+'; i++)"

Comment: Muito obrigado @Penachia, esse detalhe passou despercebido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já comentado a condição do `for` não está correta e deveria ser:

```
nome[i] != '\0' && nome[i] !='+'
```

Que significa: enquanto não chegar ao fim e enquanto não apanhar um `'+'`.

Para além disso o `cont` não está a ser incrementado dentro do `for`. Na verdade esse `cont` nem é necessário e por isso sugiro que o remova e mantenha apenas o `i` que é mais que suficiente para resolver o problema.

Reescreva para:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nome[100], num1[100];
    int i; //sem cont
    scanf("%s", nome);

    for(i = 0; nome[i] != '\0' && nome[i] !='+'; i++) {
        num1[i] = nome[i]; //utilizando so o i
    }
    num1[i] = '\0'; //com i aqui tambem
    printf("%s\n", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/cd4ya5)

Troquei o ultimo `printf` por um que mostra a `string` copiada para que fosse mais fácil de visualizar o resultado.

Penso que a ideia de mostrar o `cont` no final era mostrar até que letra foi copiada. Nesta solução o valor final do `i` tem a mesma informação, caso a queira mostrar.

Comment: Isac, li aqui(google) que o `\0` serve para delimitar o final da string. Nesse caso existe um porque de colocar `num1[i] = '\0';`? poderia me explicar?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Sim. É para a nova string ficar também com o `\0`,  caso contrário copia todos os carateres menos o delimitador final (esse não é copiado pois é onde o `for` termina). Se não tiver essa instrução faz com que a `string` não seja terminada corretamente e potencialmente dê *segmentation fault* mais à frente.

Comment: Entendido, muito obrigado o/

Answer (score 2):

Quando você estiver percorrendo a `string` basta verificar se o caracter é igual a `+`  e se for você sai do laço com um `break;`.

Vi que no final você estava exibindo um contador que não era nem incrementado, por isso exibia sempre zero, modifiquei o `printf` para exibir a string até a primeira ocorrência do `+`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nome[100], num1[100];
  int i;

  printf("Digite um texto ateh 100 caracteres:\n");
  scanf("%s", nome);

  for(i = 0; nome[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(nome[i]!='+')
        num1[i] = nome[i];
    else
        break;

  }

  num1[i] = '\0';
  printf("Nova string: %s\n", num1);
  return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que tem um problema no seu for, a comparação `i < nome[i]` (ou eu não entendi direito a lógica)

Comment: Agora que eu vi o comentário seu na do isac. O `num1[i] = '\0'` é para por o finalizador na string resultante tambem, que não era inicializada (na alocação a memória vem com dados indefinidos, se você não puser o nulo no final, ao imprimir pode receber algo como `Caiqueruf$&Pý¨$#*&hrifhr`

Comment: na verdade ficou sem lógica a primeira resposta mesmo (eu ia por o `strlen()`  no for mas não sei porque mudei no meio). A entendi vou adicionar minha resposta.

Comment: strlen é pior, vc ja vai varrer a string pra copiar, não tem razão pra varrer antes só pra saber o tamanho (até pq o strlen vai fazer exatamente isso, incrementar um contador até achar o \0).

Comment: Sim, com certeza. Quando falei "adicionar" no comentário acima me referi ao `\0`.  Agora vou tentar entender como aquele primeiro for funcionou (gerou um erro silencioso). Obrigado pela explicação não sabia dessa questão do caracter `\0`

Comment: @Bacco descobri o porque  aquele `for` funcionou. Quando eu comparava um `i` com o `char` retornado de `nome[i]` na verdade eu estava comparando um `i` com o valor ASCII do `char`, exemplo: `printf("%d \n", 96<'a'); //Retorna 1`. xD

Comment: Sim, foi um efeito colateral onde, por um "quase acaso" o \0 era o único abaixo do i para strings curtas - Mas se a string tivesse mais que 32 caracteres, em especial mais que 65 caracteres (que é o 'A') provavelmente o erro ia aparecer mais rápido. No 96 que você mencionou, ficaria "gritante". De qualquer forma, o exercício para entender o que aconteceu é proveitoso.